# Can I use reliable messaging with windows workflow and and azure service bus?

Tags: azure, workflow-foundation-4, azureservicebus

Is it possible to have a xamlx workflow which can receive a message from the service bus without deleting it and can instead call `Complete()` or `Abandon()` on the message?

Anyone got an example of that? Or is it not possible?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to start a WCF workflow service based on a servicebus message or do you want to send/receive messages in a already running workflow instance?

Comment: @fabsenet I want to send/receive messages in a already running workflow instance

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at [this codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/276400/Using-Windows-Azure-Service-Bus-Messaging#AzureMessagingActivityPack) article by Roman Kiss. Use his activities as is or take them as a starting point only.

You may as well write a bunch of activities yourself which would consume the original service bus api.

As a third solution, you could use the NetMessagingBinding to interact with the ServiceBus by using standard Send/Receive shapes.